# jquery toggle only one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i try to add jQuery script that will toggle my footer columns, my problem is how I can make to stop toggling all items. Now when someone click on H4 tags all H4 tags are toggle together.

HTML:

```
<div class="row footer-cols">
    <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h4>Information<span class="toggle"></span></h4>
                <div class="footer-cols-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h4>Why buy from us<span class="toggle"></span></h4>
                <div class="footer-cols-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Shipping & Returns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">International Shipping</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery SCRIPT

```
    jQuery('.footer .footer-cols h4').append('<span class="toggle"></span>');
    jQuery('.footer h4').on("click", function(){
        if (jQuery(this).find('span').attr('class') == 'toggle opened') { jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('opened').parents('.footer-cols').find('.footer-cols-content').slideToggle(); }
        else {
            jQuery(this).find('span').addClass('opened').parents('.footer-cols').find('.footer-cols-content').slideToggle();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the following code:

```
jQuery('.footer .footer-cols h4').append('<span class="toggle"></span>');
    jQuery('.footer-cols h4').on("click", function(){
        if (jQuery(this).find('span').attr('class') == 'toggle opened') { jQuery(this).find('span').removeClass('opened').parent().next().slideToggle();
        }
        else {
            jQuery(this).find('span').addClass('opened').parent().next().slideToggle();
        }
    });
```

The problem with your selector is that with

```
parents('.footer-cols')
```

You basically select

```
<div class="row footer-cols"></div>
```

element on top. Thus

```
find('.footer-cols-content')
```

selects all child elements in it resulting all of them to `slideToggle()`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add content to the span to give the user something to click

This one changes the plus/minus and hides other content

```
$(function() {
  $(".footer-cols").find("h4").on("click", function() {
    var $content = $(this).parent().find(".footer-cols-content");
    var $span = $(this).find("span");
    if ($span.length==0) $(this).append('<span class="toggle" />');
    $(".footer-cols-content").not($content).hide();
    $content.slideToggle();
    $span.text($span.text() == "-" ? "+" : "-");
  });
});
```

To add the span on the fly:

```
    if ($span.length==0) {
      $span=$('<span class="toggle" />');
      $(this).append($span);
    }
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".footer-cols").find("h4").on("click", function() {
    var $content = $(this).parent().find(".footer-cols-content");
    var $span = $(this).find("span");
    if ($span.length==0) {
      $span=$('<span class="toggle" />');
      $(this).append($span);
    }
    $(".footer-cols-content").not($content).hide();
    $content.slideToggle();
    $span.text($span.text() == "-" ? "+" : "-");
  });
});
```

```css
.footer-cols-content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row footer-cols">
  <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Information </h4>
        <div class="footer-cols-content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Why buy from us <span class="toggle">+</span></h4>
        <div class="footer-cols-content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping & Returns</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">International Shipping</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but i need that plus sign to be added auto, because i get that ul and h4 content dynamically

Comment: @RobertD please see update - one with the span already present, one without. Also you can add the spans on load of the data

Comment: for this last edit with span there remain 2 plus signs

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

on the click handler change `.parents('.footer-cols')` for `.parents('.col-sm-4')`

Comment: is there any way when h4 tags is open the others columns to be hidden?

Comment: Yes @RobertD. See my complete answer

Comment: where is your complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you appending `span` class but If I am not worng only slide toggle should do the work that you intend to do.

```
jQuery('.footer-cols h4').on("click", function(){
     $(this).find('span').toggleClass('opened').end().next().slideToggle();
});
```

```js
 jQuery('.footer-cols h4').on("click", function(){
             $(this).find('span').toggleClass('opened').end().next().slideToggle();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row footer-cols">
    <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h4>Information<span class="toggle"></span></h4>
                <div class="footer-cols-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h4>Why buy from us<span class="toggle"></span></h4>
                <div class="footer-cols-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Shipping & Returns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">International Shipping</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will work only when the `footer-cols-content` div is always next to h4. To avoid as such you can use `parent()`.

```
jQuery('.footer h4').on("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().find('footer-cols-content').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: i use the span to add a plus sign in the right side

Comment: @RobertD you can add/remove class without if/else condition and in one line . check my update.. :)